# Troubleshooting conda EnvironmentNameNotFound

Tags: conda

A conda environment exists but `activate` does not find it. What's going on and how do I troubleshoot it?

```
C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts>conda --version  
conda 4.9.2

C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts>.\activate.bat arcpro-clone

EnvironmentNameNotFound: Could not find conda environment: arcpro-clone
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.   



C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python
arcgispro-py3         *  C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3
arcpro-clone             d:\envs\arcpro-clone
gdal                     d:\envs\gdal
```

Checking to see if there might be a different `conda` and `activate` being used (no):

```
C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts>where conda
C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts\conda.exe

C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts>where activate
C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Windows 10 Enterprise x64.
Conda installed as part of ArcGIS Pro v2.8.

Comment: What does `conda config --show envs_dirs` give? Is the `d:\envs` directory in there?

Comment: @merv yes d:\envs was showing. After removing that entry from `%username%\%userprofile%\.conda\environments.txt` it disappeared. So it looks like not all parts of conda refer to that file. I found a work around by using junction links (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it resolved the error, so I wouldn't call it an answer, but it let met get on with my work:

- Create directory junctions in the envs directory co-located with conda.exe to the environment paths on disk
- In `%username%\%userprofile%\.conda\environments.txt` delete lines refering to these locations

```
mklink /j c:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcpro-clone d:\envs\arcpro-clone
mklink /j c:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\gdal d:\envs\gdal
```